# logon in server linux to active directory using Ansible

Tags: linux, shell, ansible, active-directory, suse

I join server Linux sles 15 sp5 to my active directory usinag ansible 2.91.
i success to join the server to domain but the i have one problem that i can't login directly via user ad, before it i should check box manually in user logon i client server and check this 2 cases in yast manually "Allow Domain User Logon" and "Create Home Directory" before login.
my object is to do all this by code to automate this task.
this is m playbook file:

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    pkgs:
      - sssd
      - sssd-tools
      - sssd-ldap
      - sssd-ad
      - adcli
      - realmd
      - krb5-client
      - openldap2-client
      - cyrus-sasl-gssapi
    AD_Domain: XXXXXXX.LOCAL
    AD_Domain_alt: XXXXXXX.local
    Join_OU: OU=Linux,DC=XXXXXXX,DC=LOCAL
    SRV_ADM_GRP_OU: OU=Linux,DC=XXXXXXX,DC=local
  vars_prompt:
    - name: username
      prompt: "Please enter your AD admin username?"
      private: no
    - name: password
      prompt: "Please enter AD admin user password?"
      private: yes
    - name: adhostname
      prompt: "Please enter the simple machine name, not fqdn format"
      private: no
  tasks:
  - name: Checking the Server Distribution Version (SLES)
    fail:
      msg: System does not run SLES, shutdown
    when: ansible_facts['distribution'] != 'SLES'
  - name: Installing the necessary packages to join the AD domain
    yum: name={{ pkgs }} state=present update_cache=yes
  - name: Configuring the machine name 
    shell: hostnamectl set-hostname {{ adhostname }}.{{ AD_Domain_alt }}
  - name: Integration with the AD domain (creation of the AD computer account and updating of the /etc/krb5.keytab file)
    shell: echo '{{ password }}' | adcli join --stdin-password {{ AD_Domain }} -U {{ username }} --domain-ou={{ Join_OU }}
  - name: Configuring the sssd.conf file
    template:
      src: sssd.j2
      dest: /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode: 0600
  - name: Configuring the nsswitch.conf file
    lineinfile:
      path: /etc/nsswitch.conf
      regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
      line: "{{ item.line }}"
    loop:
      - regexp: '^passwd:'
        line: 'passwd:   compat sss'
      - regexp: '^group:'
        line: 'group:   compat sss'
      - regexp: '^services:'                 
        line: 'services:   files sss'
      - regexp: '^sudoers:'
        line: 'sudoers:   files sss' 
  - name: Authorizing the Linux AD Admin group to connect to Linux servers
    shell: realm permit -g xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.Local
  - name: Adding Linux Admin group in sudoers
    lineinfile:
       dest: /etc/sudoers
       line: '"%YYYYYYYY@XXXXXXX.local"   ALL=(ALL) ALL'
       insertafter: '^%wheel'
  - name: Configuring the krb5.conf file
    template:
      src: krb5.j2
      dest: /etc/krb5.conf
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode: 0644
  - name: Configuring the ldap.conf client
    template:
      src: ldap.j2
      dest: /etc/openldap/ldap.conf
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode: 0644
  - name: Restarting daemon realm
    systemd:
     name: realmd
     enabled: yes
     state: restarted     
  - name: Restarting SSSD daemon
    systemd:
     name: sssd
     enabled: yes
     state: restarted
```

This is my file sssd:

```
[sssd]
domains = {{ AD_Domain }}
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam, sudo
[nss]
filter_users = root
filter_groups = root
[pam]
[sudo]
[domain/{{ AD_Domain }}]
#krb5_realm = {{ AD_Domain }}
ad_domain = {{ AD_Domain }}
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
#cache_credentials = false
id_provider = ad
auth_provider = ad
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = true
use_fully_qualified_names = false
create_homedir = true
skel_dir = /etc/skel
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
access_provider = ad
ldap_id_mapping = true
auto_private_groups = true
ldap_referrals = false
ldap_schema = ad
#chpass_provider = ad
sudo_provider = ad
simple_allow_groups = YYYYYYYYYYYYY
ad_gpo_access_control = permissive
```